# cURL PHP Newbie Needs a hand

Tags: php, curl

I am completely new to cURL requests in PHP.

I have an API that gives me the info below and wants me to send a POST request via cURL.  I've tried some basic cURL examples but have no idea what how the additional data should be sent.

API Docs contain the following:

```
curl https://api.23andme.com/token/
         -d client_id=xxx \
         -d client_secret=yyy \
         -d grant_type=authorization_code \
         -d code=zzz \
         -d "redirect_uri=https://localhost:5000/receive_code/"
         -d "scope=basic%20rs3094315"
```

Here is my example code:

```
    $data = array(
        "client_id" => $client_id, 
        "client_secret" => $client_secret,
        "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
        "code" => $code,
        "redirect_uri" => "http://localhost/23andme/",
        "scope" => "basic"
        ); 



$ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


    $response = curl_exec($ch); //Uncomment to make it live again

    if (!$response) 
    {
        return false;
    }

    echo json_decode($response);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just missed two things in your code, here is a complete example using your code as base:

```
<?php

    /* you must define an URL to POST to */
    $url = "";

    $data = array(
                  "client_id" => $client_id, 
                  "client_secret" => $client_secret,
                  "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
                  "code" => $code,
                  "redirect_uri" => "http://localhost:8080/nope",
                  "scope" => "basic"
                 ); 

    $ch = curl_init($url);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $data);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true)

          /* this line below was missing in your code */;
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));        

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    if (!$response) 
    {
        echo 'A error has occurred ' . curl_error($ch);
        return false;
    }

    echo json_decode($response);

?>
```

Try and adjust to your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I also needed to making the request over SSL.  It is working now.

Comment: You left the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` in and `CURLOPT_POST` is a boolean like the rest, not a count of the post parameters. You also can't echo out an object `echo json_decode(..)`.. AND `return false;` from an if statement? Looks like a butchered copy and paste.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
```

With your data array will send that as POST data since you already have `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

So

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Cheers

Comment: Thank you.  I'm not getting anything in my $response variable.  I should receive a JSON response either with a access token and expiration or with an error code.  I am not receiving either.  Did I translate my $data array correctly from the API specs?